# PHP Math Discrepancy

Tags: php, math, decimal, rounding

Here's some simple math, that doesn't quite add up.

**`990 / 7670 = 0.12907431`**

Assume I want to charge 1% and I start with 1000.

The same math applies above `(1000 - 1% = 990)`

Firstly:
**`990 / 7670 = 0.12907431`**

Then using my original number (+1%):
**`1000 / 0.12907431 = 7747.4750785`**

Finally to offset the 1% decrease from 1000. I increase 7670 by 1%:
**`7670 * 1.01 = 7746.7`**.

Why is there a 0.01% difference in those final two values? Is this PHP handling decimals badly?

I can't see where I'm losing that, and I feel like the math is right. I know PHP has rounding issues sometimes and wonder if it's as simple as that, or if I've missed an obv math screw up.

Comment: Further clarification on floating point- since computers are natively base 2, base 10 decimals must be approximated. Just as you can’t precisely write 1/3 in decimal, so also base 10 decimals can’t always be stored precisely in base 2. Hence, rounding is required. If you need precision with floating point numbers, consider using the [bcmath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) extension.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

990 + 1% does not equal 1000. It equals 999.9.

`990 * 1.01 = 999.9`

*That being said* - you can never rely on different floating point calculations like this to evaluate to *exactly* the correct answer. PHP, like other languages, doesn't have 'rounding issues', but instead uses floating point numbers that don't behave in exactly the same way as real numbers.

Comment: Ah of course, you cannot reverse it like that. So what you're saying is that 7670 is equivalent to 990 in this scenario. Adding 1% to 7670 = 7746.7 (999.9). But 7747.4750785 - 1% would equal 7670. And thats the difference I'm missing. If I increase the % from 1% to say 10%. The gap becomes much wider. I think this solves my problem. I just need to figure out how to code it, without knowing the original numbers (1000 or 990)

Comment: `(990 / (100 - 1%)) * 100 = 1000` . This is my solution.

Comment: `(7670 / (100 - 1)) * 100 = 7747.47`